# Node JS - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I got caught on this error so I hope you can help me.

I am trying to validate the JWT (JSON Web Token) before I process the information so I can avoid if the token is invalid, if it doesn't exist, if it's expired or if it was used already.

Everything works fine but i got this warning on console

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

here is my code

````
    try {
        const token = req.header("Authorization")

        if (!token)
            return res.formatter.unauthorized("No existe el token");

        let verified = {}
        
        jwt.verify(getAccessToken(token), process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, verifiedJWT) => {
            if(err){
                if(err.message === "jwt expired"){
                    return res.formatter.unauthorized('Token expired');
                }
            }else{
                verified = verifiedJWT;
            }
        });

        if (!verified)
            return res.formatter.unauthorized("Invalid token");

        const tokenInvalid = await TokensInvalid.findOne({ tokenInvalid: token });
        if (tokenInvalid)
            return res.formatter.unauthorized('Token already used');
        
        req.token = token;
        req.user = verified.user;
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        return res.formatter.serverError(err.message)
    }
};```

Hope you can support me. Thank you all!
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your code inside the `jwt.verify()` callback.  It is non-blocking and asynchronous so the code after it will execute before the callback, not after.  To fix, move that code inside the callback itself:

But, even better since you're already using `await` in this function is to use a promisified version of `jwt.verify()`.

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
jwt.verifyP = promisify(jwt.verify);

try {
    const token = req.header("Authorization")

    if (!token)
        return res.formatter.unauthorized("No existe el token");

    // see if this token is verified
    let verified = await jwt.verifyP(getAccessToken(token), process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    if (!verified) {
        return res.formatter.unauthorized("Invalid token");
    }
} catch (err) {
    // decide which jwt error to send
    if (err.message === "jwt expired") {
        res.formatter.unauthorized('Token expired');
    } else {
        res.formatter.unauthorized("Invalid token");
    }
    return;
}

try {
    // check if token is in database as an invalid one
    const tokenInvalid = await TokensInvalid.findOne({ tokenInvalid: token });
    if (tokenInvalid) {
        return res.formatter.unauthorized('Token already used');
    }

    req.token = token;
    req.user = verified.user;
    next();
    return;
} catch (err) {
    return res.formatter.serverError(err.message)
}
```